# D3 select: submit form dynamically?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using D3. I have click-handling code for an input to stop form submission and do some validation. Then if validation succeeds, I want to submit the form.

How do I submit the form programmatically, using D3 selectors? `form.submit()` says the submit method does not exist. (I'm confident that `form` is the form element.)

I'm also trying `form.dispatch('submit')` but that does not work either:

```
import { select as $, event as d3_event } from "d3";
$(el).on("click", function() {
  // prevent form submission
  d3_event.stopPropagation();
  d3_event.preventDefault();
  // later, submit form?
  var form = $(this.parentNode);
  form.dispatch('submit');
}
```

My HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="myaction">
   <button class="create-new btn popup"><i class="fa fa-external-link"></i> Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm not using jQuery. It's all D3.

Comment: Sorry, only now I'm seeing `select as $`! Well, that's very confusing, I bet a lot of people will think that is jQuery! I deleted my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a `submit` event in the predefined list of events for a `d3` node. Here's an approach that fires the submit event by selecting the DOM node using `node()` function. (Btw I'm not using imports here)

```js
d3.select('#submit').on('click', function() {
  // prevent form submission
  d3.event.stopPropagation();
  d3.event.preventDefault();
  // later, submit form?
  var form = d3.select(this.parentNode).node();
  form.submit();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>

<form id="myform" action="submit-form.php">
Search: <input type='text' name='query'>
<a href="#" id="submit">Submit</a>
</form>
```

Another approach I can think of as of now is define a **custom** event listener for submit and **dispatch** it which would still look for the `DOM` node in the listener function. (i.e. basically calling `<form>`'s built-in `submit()` function.